# Standalone Crystal Reports with a .NET C# ViewModel

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, viewmodel

Im using standalone version of Crystal Reports 2016. In the integrated visual studio version you can connect to a datasource which is a view model from the project. I cant see how to do this in the standalone version. Given they produce the same file and I can open either type with either option, it should be possible.

Can anyone advise which datasource option to select to use standalone with .net models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports Designer cannot access a ViewModel in your application.

You would need to materialize the data into a standard data source (database table, CSV, Excel, ...) in order for Crystal Reports Designer to have access to it.

Comment: I just want the model, ie the structure of the data, like you can do in Crystal for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to SAP's Crystal Reports Viewer?  It does not support refreshing data.

Comment: No im referring to the standalone designer accessing a view model from a c# .net project as a datasource